# How do I set focus on an anchor?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to activate a link by setting focus to it and sending an enter key.

```
example = find{:xpath,'//*[@id="whatever"]/div/a')
example.trigger(focus)
example.send_keys(:enter}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: why aren't you using click method?

Comment: sometimes find ```find(:xpath,[such and such]).click``` fails, and I require a second method.  ruby is notorious for many ways to reach the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an empty key to the element, so it gets focused.

```
example.send_keys ""
```

Comment: Sanjay, thank you that worked perfectly ```def xclick(selector)
  find(:xpath, selector).click
end

def xclick2(selector)
  find(:xpath, selector).send_keys('')
  find(:xpath, selector).send_keys(:enter)
end```

Comment: @TangibleDream Glad to Help :)